# Sort query after translation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, translation

I do a query. It is fine. I can list my categories very well. But I do have couple languages. The result from my db is in English. How can I sort the result after I translate in the html.php-template. Or do I have to do it in the action?

Of course my translation in symfony2 looks like this: `$this->get('translator')->trans('title.imprint')`

Thanks for a hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to answer my own question, so somebody might use it. I use usort and strcmp.

```
$categories_db = $this->em->getRepository('FrontendContentBundle:CategoriesAllocation')
                        ->findBy(array('state' => $state_id,
                            'module' => $module_id
                        ));

    usort($categories_db, function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($this->translator->trans($a->getCategory()->getCategory(), array(), 'categories'), $this->translator->trans($b->getCategory()->getCategory(), array(), 'categories'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use twig [sort](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/sort.html) function, which will sort your query like php [asort](https://www.php.net/asort) function. Another way is to use [TwigExtension](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html). With this you can create your own filter.